# Sublime Text: how to see current working directory, and how to change it

Tags: sublimetext2

Q1: How do I see what the current working directory is in Sublime Text?

I want to know so I know which directories/subdirectories it's searching when I do a text search.

Q2: Also, is there a way to change the current working directory?

Sublime Text 2, v2.0.1, build 2217; Mac OS X Lion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a "Find in Files", it searches the folders/files listed in the "Where:" field.  If nothing is specified, I believe this defaults to all the files/folders in the project.  You can change this by specifying different value(s) in the "Where:" field, and add further criteria by clicking on the "..." icon next to the "Where:" value to get options of `Clear, Add Folder, Add Include Filter, Add Exclude Filter, Add Open Folders, Add Open Files`

Another option to restrict your search is to do a "File > Open..." and open the folder where you want to search.  This opens a new window with a new project.

I generally open a folder so it brings up a new window, then `Project -> Save Project As` to save the project. There is also a command in the command palette to do this. You can then quickly switch between projects by using the shortcut `cmd+ctrl+p`.

Comment: Thanks @skuroda! That's what I was looking for.  Opening a new folder opens/creates a new project, and the text search is then done from that folder.

Answer (score 2):

The current working directory in ST can be opened in the Finder by right-clicking anywhere in an open file and selecting "Reveal in Finder".

At any rate, the concept of a 'current working directory' is meaningful in ST only in the context of a project which itself is a folder and all the files in it (except the ones filtered out by the project file). That would preclude the possibility of changing the working directory straight away, I should think

Answer (score 1):

What about this: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html.
The **working_dir** options can change the current work directory.
May be this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @waterfox0323.  However, it indicates that a command is required, and "The original current directory is restored afterwards."  So this is only for running external commands, not just changing the directory for the currently open project in Sublime.